# calculate percentage and display in a texview android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, math, textview, calc

I am developing an application where I pass 1 variables int through a string of an activity to next activity, in the next activity I take that string and return it again and an int, then I calculate a percentage and display and a textview, the past variable and approx1 so I check if it is not empty, then I calculate the percentage ex: ((3/45) * 100) and display in a text view, reviewing again for string ... but in any way I make a mistake, what can be ?

```
    Bundle bundle = getIntent (). GetExtras ();
    String aprox1 = bundle.getString ("aprox1");
    if (aprox1! = null)
    try {
    num3 = Integer.parseInt (aprox1);
    result = Math.round ((num3 / 45) * 100);
    TextView counter2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView16);
    String abcString2 = Integer.toString (result);
    counter2.setText (abcString2);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) { 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have {} after the if statement like so:

```
  if (aprox1! = null) {
    try {
    num3 = Integer.parseInt (aprox1);
    result = Math.round ((num3 / 45) * 100);
    TextView counter2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView16);
    String abcString2 = Integer.toString (result);
    counter2.setText (abcString2);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) { 
    }
}
```

Its also worth noting that because num3 is an integer when you divide it by 45 you will get an **Integer** not a percentage.

To fix this issue, make num3 a double or cast either num3 or 45 to a double before computing the division.

For example, a simple fix would include changing line 4 to the following:

```
result = Math.round ((num3 / 45.0) * 100);
```